# How to convert WriteableBitmap to byte[] in Windows Phone 8.1 Store app

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1, arrays, writeablebitmapex

I want to convert a WriteableBitmap to byte[] and there are tons of examples in Internet yet not a single one works, or has methods that are not current in my runtime which is Windows Phone 8.1 store project.
Here is my WriteableBitmap object.

```
BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/no_pic.png", UriKind.Absolute));
WriteableBitmap DefaultPhotoBmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmpImage.PixelWidth, bmpImage.PixelHeight);
```

When using

```
DefaultPhotoBmp.ToByteArray();
```

from WriteableBitmapEx library I dont think it turns the image inside into a byte array but the WriteableBitmap object into a byte array.. I need the image

All I want to do is convert the picture inside in byte array and send it via HTTP. How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351545/converting-writeablebitmap-to-byte-array-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight

Comment: This does not work under Windows Phone 8.1 store app.. 'IBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'AsStream' and the best extension method overload 'WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsStream(IRandomAccessStream)' requires a receiver of type 'IRandomAccessStream'

Comment: I think you tried the wrong example at that link, look at the accepted answer example.

Comment: Again this is a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app. SaveJpeg() method of WriteableBitmap is not present..