# Convert BitmapImage to byte[]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, arrays

I have problem with converting BitmapImage to byte[]. I tried a lot of solutions and nothing works, every time i get different errors.

For example i found nice solutions but it also doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1.

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(BitmapImage img)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(img);
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        img = null;
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

this was taken from here:  [Convert Bitmap Image to byte array (Windows phone 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241480/convert-bitmap-image-to-byte-array-windows-phone-8)

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'pixelHeight' of 'WriteableBitmap.WriteableBitmap(int, int)'
>
> The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

or if somebody has got another idea how to convert it, please post it. Thanks a lot for any help!

I also tried this: [BitmapImage to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte)

but there was problem with usings

> 'BitmapImage' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' and 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'

so I used "BitmapEncoder" but it doesn't have method like Save and Frame.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676/bitmapimage-to-byte

Comment: I tried to use this solutions but with JpegBitmapEncoder  there is a lot of errors between using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; and using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging; then I use BitmapEncoder  but it doesn't have method like .Save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it can't be done on this platform. I change my project to Windows Phone Silverlight/8.0 and there is working everything.

```
 public static BitmapImage BytesToImage(byte[] bytes)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
                return bitmapImage;
            }
        }
        finally { bitmapImage = null; }
    }

    public static byte[] ImageToBytes(BitmapImage img)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(img);
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            img = null;
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

see the below link it might help

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/713c0ed1-d979-43ef-8857-bbe0b35576a9/windows-8-how-to-convert-bitmapimage-into-byte?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, which are subject to bit-rot and provide very little information in and of themselves.

Comment: Yes I found it also but I'm still getting "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'pixelHeight' of 'WriteableBitmap.WriteableBitmap(int, int)'" when in code is WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(img);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myImage);
      wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myImage.PixelWidth, myImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
      byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

You can also use extension method here

```
      public static class MyExtensions
      {
          public static Byte[] ByteFromImage(this System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage imageSource)
          {
            Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
            Byte[] imagebyte = null;
            if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
            {
               using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
               {
                 imagebyte = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
               }
            }

              return imagebyte;
          }
       }
```

and then call

```
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage myImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        byte[] imageBytes = myImage.ByteFromImage();
```

Comment: It gives me the same error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'pixelHeight' of 'WriteableBitmap.WriteableBitmap(int, int)'

Comment: After your edit:

I tried it and I'm getting this error on this line: "Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;"

'BitmapImage' does not contain a definition for 'StreamSource' and no extension method 'StreamSource' accepting a first argument of type 'BitmapImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what is the namespace for `BitmapImage` ?

Comment: It's using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks but what referencee I need to add? PresentationCore.dll ? It's not going to work with Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do any transformation on the image, you'll want to use the appropriate image encoder, then do something like below.  If you're working with a multi-frame image (eg TIF), you need to add the frames one at a time to the encoder or you'll only get the first frame of the image.

```
MemoryStream ms = null;
TiffBitmapEncoder enc = null

enc = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
enc.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4;
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpImg));
using (ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  enc.Save(ms);
}
return ms.ToArray();
```